# Directive not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am newbie to Angularjs. I am trying to create simple directive with the following code:

View:

```
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<user-info></user-info>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);    
myapp.directive('userInfo', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */
    directive.template = "My first directive: ";
    return directive;
});
```

I am following this Tutorial to learn directive 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

I am getting error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A53)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20w.bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A296)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A46%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381
```

Here is my codepen link
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGNKxz

Comment: you aren't including your own code in page. Follow link in error for more details. Also , using development version of angular.js will give more verbose error and stack trace output in console

Comment: a typo in ng-app module name camelcase `myapp` vs `myApp` ?

Comment: I've add my codepen link, please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in the name of your app :

myapp = angular.module("my**A**pp", []); // not 'myapp'

Comment: Ok. That was my silly mistake. thank for help though

Answer (score 1):

**Add Your Directive**

You need to add the directive to your html like so

```
<script src="path/to/your/directive.js"></script>
```

or if your working from one module you will link to the main module. But please restructure your app like [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) it will keep code up to standard and clean.

I have a git hub repo where I am building an app in this structure [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight). Best of luck.

**Note**

You are using angular min. Min is great for production because its small and faster to load but your in development at the moment so use the full version so you can capture errors better with the browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your useful not. I'll try to get something from it

Comment: It can really help with debugging if you add the full version. You get real errors in the console. But really chek out the app structure I've been working from. Hopefully I will have a directive up there soon.

Comment: Thanks. its really helpful for newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not declare the controller myCtrl. Your directive looks fine.

```
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function() {
});
```

Comment: Nope. it doesn't work. I have tried to add controller.

Comment: Did you include your script? I don't see any <script> tags in your code  @Arvaan

Comment: I added script for angularjs. I don't think so, I should add any script for directive

Answer (score 0):

Is it the current version of your html file ?

Because you might need to link your controller, between head tags, insert :

1. `<script src="the js file which contains your controller"></script>`

or

2. `<script>Your controller</script>`